# Convert numbers to date

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to convert numbers (`int`) from an array into date format, to plot it in `matplotlib`.

My problem is that some years have months with them and some don't.
I split the array in year and year+month. 
Now i am stuck, hopefully someone can help.

```
listyear = ['1967', '1968', '1969', '1970', '1971', '1972', '1973', 
'1974', '1975', '1976', '1977', '1978', '1979', '1980', '1981', '1982', 
'1983', '1984', '1985', '1986', '1987', '1988', '1989', '1990', '1991', 
'1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', 
'2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', 
'2010', '2011', '2012']

listyearandmonth = ['01.2013', '11.2013', '03.2014', '12.2014']
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: what is your input and what output do you want?

Comment: do you care about the month or can you amend it? If you do care, should the years withoud months be considered as January first of that year or something similar?

Comment: @MorganThrapp: Your comment _was_ constructive. There's a [meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298425/has-the-what-have-you-tried-comment-policy-changed) about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not mentioned any date-related data, all I do is converting the given years from both lists to [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#available-types) objects as mentioned in [Matplotlib's date API](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html) or [date demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import datetime

listyear = ['1967', '1968', '1969', '1970', '1971', '1972', '1973', 
'1974', '1975', '1976', '1977', '1978', '1979', '1980', '1981', '1982', 
'1983', '1984', '1985', '1986', '1987', '1988', '1989', '1990', '1991', 
'1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', 
'2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', 
'2010', '2011', '2012']

listyearandmonth = ['01.2013', '11.2013', '03.2014', '12.2014']

# Extract years from the given list and extend those to list `listyear`
# Assumption: Dates given in list `listyearandmonth` have the format <MM.YYYY>
listyear.extend([y[1] for y in [s.split('.') for s in listyearandmonth]])

# Convert years given in list `listyear` to `datetime.date` objects
# Assumption: Do not care about month and day (set both to 1)
datetime_yrs = [datetime.date(int(y), 1, 1) for y in listyear]
```